# Facebook cover photo with graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I wonder if it is possible to get the cover photo in just one call.

Like > https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/picture?type=square gives you the photo right away.

Is it possible to do the same with this  > https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID?fields=cover

without having to parse it with json?

What i want is the coverphoto right away.

Thanx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Facebooks' Cover Photo via PHP SDK & Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8125880/getting-facebooks-cover-photo-via-php-sdk-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if it is possible to get the cover photo in just one call.

No you can't.

You may use FB api instead-

```
$albumCover = $facebook->api("/[album_id]?fields=picture", "get");

echo "<img src='".$albumCover['picture']."' />";
```

Adding just one extra line wont bother you I guess.

Comment: Then in that case, it would be nice if you can share your answer.

Comment: Actually it does....
I am already calling my page feed to get all the status and comments.
The thing i want to do is to show both the cover photo and profile pic, name and message in the rows. But to make a call for the cover photo i would have to use data.from.id to make the > https://graph.facebook.com/data.from.id?fields=cover and then parse data.cover.source to get the image. And i dont know how to get that to work.....